# Are object parameters passed as references in Javascript to functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript code:

```
var oLink = {
        title:   $link.attr('title') || '',
        row:     $link.attr('data-row') || '',
        $modal:  ''
    }
```

I now call a function like this:

```
oLink.$modal = accessModalOpen(oLink, content);
```

Do I need to return oLink.$modal or could I just set it inside accessModalOpen? In other words is the parameter oLink passed as a reference in javascript?

**Update:**

Added $modal to the oLink declaration

Comment: You could simply find that yourself, by trying the two different cases.

Comment: As much as "if it works" I'm hoping to get some advice on is this a good thing to do. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"In other words is the parameter oLink passed as a reference in javascript?"*

Yes. Within your function, you will have a reference to the same object, not a copy of the object, so yes you can update, add and delete object properties within your function.

Note though that it's not "pass by reference" in the sense that some languages have it. The variable outside the function and the parameter used inside the function will both refer to the same object, which is why you can change its properties, but if you assign the function parameter to some other object that doesn't affect the variable outside the function which will continue to refer to the original object.

Answer (score 3):

With your current setup, you should return it. `oLink` **is** passed as a reference, so you can set it inside of the function too, but then you'd have this instead:

```
accessModalOpen(oLink, content);
```

[Demo to help you understand](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/8e7fM/)

Comment: Can you explain why you think I should return it. I updated my question slightly and included $modal to the oLink declaration. Thanks

Comment: Well, in your current setup, if you didn't return it, in the end, `oLink.$modal` would be undefined. It'd be set inside the function, then the function would end, it'd return nothing, which is `undefined`, and this return value would be set to the variable, making it `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Both will achieve the same result *in this specific case*, but it depends on the actual semantics of the `oLink.$modal` property. If that property is closely tied to the logic of `accessModalOpen`, then you should set it *inside* `accessModalOpen`; if there would be situations where `accessModalOpen` *shouldn't* set `oLink.$modal`, but you would still need that value in some other way, you should return it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/r8anu/)

```
var $link = {
    attr:function(str) { return str; }
}

function accessModalOpen(obj,cont) {
    return "Modal: accessed "+obj.title+" with "+cont.text;
}    
function accessModalOpen1(obj,cont) {
    obj.$modal1= "Modal1: accessed "+obj.title+" with "+cont.text;
}    
var content = {
    text:"This is content"
}    
var oLink = {
  title:   $link.attr('object title') || '',
  row:     $link.attr('data-row') || ''
}

oLink.$modal = accessModalOpen(oLink, content); // return content and set
alert(oLink.$modal); 

accessModalOpen1(oLink, content); // just set
alert(oLink.$modal1); 
​
```

Comment: You see the `return` in `accessModalOpen`? That's what he's talking about. He's asking if he can simply set the value in there instead of having a value `return`ed.

Comment: Ahh - NOW I understand. Updated to reflect either

Answer (score 1):

To help (or hinder... we'll see), JS passes non-scalar objects by reference, but passes scalar objects by value.

```
var x = 10;
function increment (num) { num += 1; }

increment(x);
console.log(x); // 10;
```

Meanwhile:

```
var bob = {
    name : "Bob",
    age : 32,
    job : "Shoe Salesman",
    salary : 2000000
};

function fire (employee) {
    delete employee.job;
    employee.unemployed = true;
    employee.salary = 0;
}

fire(bob); // { name : "Bob", age : 32, unemployed : true, salary : 0 }
```

So if you're passing an object or a function into a function, you will be able to add/modify properties.
If you pass an array, you will be able to push items into it, or pop items out of it.

If you're passing a string or a number or a boolean, you need to use the return value
(but if you pass an object, you can modify one of its properties to be a scalar value).

Answer (score 0):

Like all JavaScript parameters, oLink will be passed to the function *accessModalOpen* by value.  However, oLink itself is only a reference to the location in the global heap where the contents of the oLink object are stored.  This means that you can modify the properties on oLink from within your function and those modifications will continue to be visible after the function returns.

If you were to reassign oLink to a new object within *accessModalOpen*, then that change would not be visible after the function returned.  This means you could not do something like creating a new oLink object if it was unassigned.

The short answer is that you can modify oLink within the function, just as you are asking.  But be aware that if you do anything that changes the object that oLink is referencing, then those changes would be thrown away after the function returns (in the outer scope).  This can lead to some hard to track bugs if you do not understand it.

There is a really good write up that I will link below on how JavaScript handles parameter passing that I highly recommend.  It goes into much more detail on exactly what is happening.

[JavaScript parameter passing](http://www.chaosincomputing.com/2015/08/javascript-parameter-passing/)